# Parallel Quicksort using OpenMP giving slower results

Tags: arrays, c, parallel-processing, openmp, quicksort

This is my parallel section in the QuickSort algorithm

```
void quicksort_recursion(int array[], int low, int high) {
if (low < high) {
    int pivot_index = partition(array, low, high);

#pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(2)
    {
#pragma omp section
            {
            quicksort_recursion(array, low, pivot_index - 1);
            }

#pragma omp section
            {
            quicksort_recursion(array, pivot_index + 1, high);
            }
       }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting up to 3 times slower results with OMP compared to results without it (0.6 s without OMP and 2.18 using it) Also changing the number of threads seems to make no difference. Im compiling the code using `gcc -o openmp01 -fopenmp example.c`
Any ideas why the slower results might be happening and how to fix them are appreciated.

Here is the rest of the code

```
//
// Created by XPC on 1/12/2023.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>
//#include "listamuylarga.c"

#define SIZE 500000

int generateList(int list[], int size);
void swap(int *x, int *y);
void quicksort(int array[], int lenght);
void quicksort_recursion(int array[], int low, int high);
int partition(int array[], int low, int high);

int generateList(int list[], int size) {

    srand(time(NULL)); // Seed the random number generator

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        list[i] = rand() % 1000; // Generates random numbers between 0 and 999 (adjust as needed)
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[SIZE];
    generateList(a, SIZE);
    int length = SIZE;
    clock_t begin = clock();
    quicksort(a, length);

    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

//    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
//        printf(" %d", a[i]);
//    };

    printf("\n");
    printf("Tiempo: %f", time_spent);
// printf("First element of myList: %d\n", myList[0]);

    return 0;
}
void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
void quicksort(int array[], int length)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    quicksort_recursion(array, 0, length-1);
}

void quicksort_recursion(int array[], int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int pivot_index = partition(array, low, high);

#pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(2)
        {
#pragma omp section
            {
                quicksort_recursion(array, low, pivot_index - 1);
            }

#pragma omp section
            {
                quicksort_recursion(array, pivot_index + 1, high);
            }
        }
    }
}
int partition(int array[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot_index = low + (rand() % (high - low)); // numero random entre low y high
    if (pivot_index != high);
        swap(&array[pivot_index], &array[high]);
    int pivot_value = array[high];
    int i = low;
    for (int j = low; j < high; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] <= pivot_value)
        {
            swap(&array[i], &array[j]);
            i++;
        }
    }
swap(&array[i], &array[high]);
return i;
}
```

Comment: `generateList()` doesn't return a value, and I think it's best practice to just call srand() once in the start of main.

Comment: `if (pivot_index != high);` is if statement without a body is a defect in your code.  Remove the `;`.

Comment: You have to do the partitioning stage also in parallel. That's not simple. Hint: it's a "parallel prefix" operation.

Comment: Only the first partitioning is serial, @VictorEijkhout.  It would be more efficient for that to be parallel too, but not by a factor of 3.

Comment: Not that it should matter but partition is a little funky... You pick an index from [low; high[ then if it's not high swap them but you already excluded high.

Comment: Parallelization has overhead, and if you're not careful, that can swamp any gains from concurrent computation.  That is likely what is happening here.  Generally speaking, parallel computations are best done in a small number of large pieces, but your approach uses a very large number of pieces, some of them very small.

Comment: On my system I see about a step-wise function 1.6s to 0.9s when going from <8 to >8 threads on an 4c/8t machine.  It doesn't make much sense to me as there is only two sections. Never used omp, I wonder how it knows that the array is non-overlapping between threads

Comment: It *doesn't* know, @AllanWind.  OMP leaves it to the programmer to avoid data races and a variety of other issues that can make parallel computations incorrect.  And there are far more than two sections.  There are two *for every partitition*.  Overall, that looks like about 2n sections to me.

Comment: Doesn't this create nlog(n) threads?  If I move the parallel section to `quicksort()` so we only create 2 threads I get 0.1s for non-parallel and 0.16 for parallel with 2 threads.

Comment: No, it doesn't @AllanWind.  OMP does not spawn a new thread for each section, and there are only about 2n sections overall in the OP's computation anyway.  Additionally, it's not clear to me exactly what your variant is, but it would take more than just moving the OMP directives around to convert the OP's code to run exactly two sections.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah, obviously, sorting the two half of the array would subsequently require  a merge but I was just curios of what it did to run-time.

Comment: If I run the program with `OMP_WAIT_POLICY=passive ./a.out` it seems to drop the run-time to 0.9s most of the time.  Clang is 1.8s and with `OMP_WAIT_POLICY=passive` it drops to 0.5s.

Comment: If you changed <= to < you swap fewer elements as you have a lot of duplicates. A run with profiling and debugging enabled takes 1.7s and gprof reports 97.43% of the time (0.36) in partition so not super helpful. I.e. this supports the theory that it's overhead in openmp.

Comment: If I change 1000 to SIZE (i.e. few duplicates) gcc run-time with `OMP_WAIT_POLICY=passive` drops to ~0.6.

Comment: One other thing, `clock()` measures processor time used.  You might be more interested in wall-time `Tiempo: 0.603513` vs `time ./a.out .. real    0m0.470s`

Comment: Indeed you should use the `omp_get_wtime()` function to measure the elapsed time, which is what you are really interested in.

Comment: Also, you are using nested parallelism, but have you checked that it is enabled? sometimes it is not by default. At the beginning of your code you should execute `omp_set_nested(1); omp_set_max_active_levels(5)`. Note however that nested parallelism is often not very efficient.